# Displaying Months Dynamically for the given Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement where I need to return the months dynamically from the given date.

For example, If the Input is `2018-05-20`, Then the output should be

```
May
June
July
'
'
'
April
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question in your question. Are you saying that for any given date, you want the names of that month and the 11 afterwards?  What have you tried so far? What is your question exactly?

Comment: Yes Exactly, for any given date, I want the names of that month and the 11 afterwards. I have tried using recursive cte with no luck.

Comment: @Ram update the question and post what you want there

Comment: @Ram if you use a calendar table the query becomes trivial

Comment: *"I have tried using recursive cte with no luck."* and post your attempt too when you make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use cte recursive.

Start date is today, enddate is next year today.

`cte recursive` condition is compare every add one month.

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE(startDt,endDt) AS (
   SELECT  CAST('2018-05-20' AS DATE) startDt, DATEADD (year,1,'2018-05-20') endDt
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(month,1,startDt) ,endDt
   FROM CTE
   WHERE DATEADD(month,1,startDt) < endDt
)
SELECT datename(month, startDt)
FROM CTE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/35576/0)**:

```
|           |
|-----------|
|       May |
|      June |
|      July |
|    August |
| September |
|   October |
|  November |
|  December |
|   January |
|  February |
|     March |
|     April |
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use a tally table, rather than an rCTE. Considering you only need 0-11 you could easily "hard code" the values:

```
DECLARE @Date date = '20180520';

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, V.M, @Date))
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)) V(M)
ORDER BY V.M;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it meet your requirement?

```
-- TEST DATA
declare @my_date as date = '2018-05-20';

-- SOLUTION
with cte as (
select DATENAME(month,@my_date) name, CAST(1 as int) lvl
union all 
select DATENAME(month,dateadd(month,cte.lvl,@my_date)),cte.lvl + 1 from cte where cte.lvl <12
)
select name as [Month Name] from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below way

```
DECLARE 
        @DateFrom DATETIME = GETDATE(),
        @DateTo DATETIME =  DATEADD(month, 11,  GETDATE());

    WITH DateGenerate 
    AS (
        SELECT @DateFrom as MyDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, MyDate)
        FROM DateGenerate
        WHERE MyDate < @DateTo
       )

    SELECT 
        DATENAME(month, MyDate)
    FROM 
        DateGenerate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way

```
DECLARE @Date date = '20180520';

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, V.[Numbers], @Date)) AS Months
FROM (
SELECT  TOP (11 - 0+1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S.[object_id])+(0 - 1) [Numbers]
FROM    sys.all_objects S WITH (NOLOCK)
) V
```